# Evaluating Orbeon 4.10 PE

Tags: orbeon, xforms

Currently, we consider Orbeon 4.10 PE for one of our projects. There are 3 open questions we´d need to get answered:

1. Orbeon CE is licenced under LGPL conditions. This means that users can   customize Orbeon and even use this customized software in proprietary products (weak copyleft). If you used the PE edition, could you still customize Orbeon? In other terms: is the PE edition also LGPL-licenced?
2. For our project, we´d need to add some custom form fields in the form builder. Is this possible / allowed in the PE edition? Are there some references how to add new types of form elements in the form builder?
3. You offer licences for each server per year. Is it also possible to get a PE licence independent from the number of used servers?

Thank you very much and best regards
Ben

Comment: The orbeon tag you added to the question states: `Use this tag for technical questions such as scripting issues, form behavior, etc. Non-technical questions should be directed to the Orbeon community at the official site.`. As this is a nontechnical question, I'm voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a non technical question about Orbeon that should be asked on the Orbeon site.

Comment: @fvu, I agree, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Yet, I still answered below, so Ben can get an answer to his questions ASAP.

Comment: Ben, Stack Overflow is intended to be used for programming questions. Your second question falls in that category, but not so much the first, and definitely not the third. In the future, for non-technical "business" questions I'd recommend you just email us at `info@orbeon.com`. And for quick questions of any type, if you're on Twitter, feel free to send a tweet to `@orbeon` (https://twitter.com/orbeon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **PE source**. Orbeon Forms CE is open source, and licensed under the LGPL license. Orbeon Forms PE is *not* open source, but as of this writing, PE customers can ask for the source, so they can investigate issues, facilitate integrations, or even make changes to Orbeon Forms PE. They can use those versions they modified, as long as they maintain a PE license. For more on this, see the question *Is the source of Orbeon Forms PE available?* on the [PE pricing page](http://www.orbeon.com/pricing).
2. **Custom fields**. Yes, you can create your own custom fields and add them to the sidebar in Form Builder. For more on this, see the [documentation on XBL components](http://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xbl/index.html), and of course should you have a more specific question about this topic, feel free to ask it here.
3. **Possibility to license independently of the number of servers**.  As you gathered from the web site, the generic answer is *no*, but if you feel that you have a unique situation that should be considered, I'd recommend you send an email to `info@orbeon.com` to enquire about this.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. How can custom fields be added to the form builder if the PE version is not open source?

Comment: @BenSchnarr Whether you're using the CE or PE, adding components doesn't require any change to source of Orbeon Forms. Just like, say, creating an app for iOS doesn't require any change to the source of iOS :). There is a way for you to package your HTML/JavaScript/CSS into an XBL component, and point Orbeon Forms to that component so it adds it to the sidebar.